# Query SQL Server - Union

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Galera, a seguinte consulta abaixo através do *union* está trazendo da seguinte forma.

> ```
> Consultor          UsuID     Tentativa 1 Abertos
> Gabriela Sousa     95093             17
> Gabriela Sousa     95093             32
> ```

Mas eu quero trazer da seguinte forma:

> ```
> Consultor          UsuID     Tentativa 1 Abertos
> Gabriela Sousa     95093             49
> ```

```
select
U.UsuNome Consultor,
       U.UsuID, 
       (COUNT((S.SolID))) AS [Tentativa 1 Abertos]
from Solicitacao S 
left join Usuario U on U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel
WHERE U.UsuTipo = 'A' AND U.UsuIDGrupo = 30 AND U.EmpLiberada = 1 and u.UsuUsuario is not null
and S.SolEstagioID IN (235,276,278,294) AND S.SolStatus IN (0,1,5)-- AND S.UsuIDCliente not in (select Y.UsuIDCliente from Solicitacao Y where Y.SolTipID in (710) and Y.SolStatus in (0,1,5))
GROUP BY U.UsuID, U.UsuNome

union

select
U.UsuNome Consultor,
       U.UsuID, 
       (COUNT((S.TarID))) AS [Tentativa 1 Abertos]
from Tarefa S 
left join Usuario U on U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel
WHERE U.UsuTipo = 'A' AND U.UsuIDGrupo = 30 AND U.EmpLiberada = 1 and u.UsuUsuario is not null
and S.TarEstagioID IN (235,276,278,294) AND S.TarStatus IN (0,1,5)-- AND S.UsuIDCliente not in (select Y.UsuIDCliente from Solicitacao Y where Y.SolTipID in (710) and Y.SolStatus in (0,1,5))
GROUP BY U.UsuID, U.UsuNome
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A questão é que o [union](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) traz realmente linhas diferentes, então você precisa apenas agrupar esses resultados em um único:

```
SELECT Consultor, UsuID, SUM([Tentativa 1 Abertos])
FROM (
    select U.UsuNome Consultor, U.UsuID, (COUNT((S.SolID))) AS [Tentativa 1 Abertos]
    from Solicitacao S 
    left join Usuario U on U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel
    WHERE U.UsuTipo = 'A' AND U.UsuIDGrupo = 30 AND U.EmpLiberada = 1 and u.UsuUsuario is not null
    and S.SolEstagioID IN (235,276,278,294) AND S.SolStatus IN (0,1,5)-- AND S.UsuIDCliente not in (select Y.UsuIDCliente from Solicitacao Y where Y.SolTipID in (710) and Y.SolStatus in (0,1,5))
    GROUP BY U.UsuID, U.UsuNome

    union

    select U.UsuNome Consultor, U.UsuID, (COUNT((S.TarID))) AS [Tentativa 1 Abertos]
    from Tarefa S 
    left join Usuario U on U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel
    WHERE U.UsuTipo = 'A' AND U.UsuIDGrupo = 30 AND U.EmpLiberada = 1 and u.UsuUsuario is not null
    and S.TarEstagioID IN (235,276,278,294) AND S.TarStatus IN (0,1,5)-- AND S.UsuIDCliente not in (select Y.UsuIDCliente from Solicitacao Y where Y.SolTipID in (710) and Y.SolStatus in (0,1,5))
    GROUP BY U.UsuID, U.UsuNome
) as tabela
GROUP BY Consultor, UsuID
```

Comment: show de bola. Obrigado @rLinhares.

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer outro select.

```
select Consultor, UsuID , sun([Tentativa 1 Abertos])
From
(
    select
    U.UsuNome Consultor, U.UsuID, (COUNT((S.SolID))) AS [Tentativa 1 Abertos]
    from Solicitacao S 
    left join Usuario U on U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel
    WHERE U.UsuTipo = 'A' AND U.UsuIDGrupo = 30 AND U.EmpLiberada = 1 and u.UsuUsuario is not null
    and S.SolEstagioID IN (235,276,278,294) AND S.SolStatus IN (0,1,5)-- AND S.UsuIDCliente not in (select Y.UsuIDCliente from Solicitacao Y where Y.SolTipID in (710) and Y.SolStatus in (0,1,5))
    GROUP BY U.UsuID, U.UsuNome

    union

    select
    U.UsuNome Consultor,
           U.UsuID, 
           (COUNT((S.TarID))) AS [Tentativa 1 Abertos]
    from Tarefa S 
    left join Usuario U on U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel
    WHERE U.UsuTipo = 'A' AND U.UsuIDGrupo = 30 AND U.EmpLiberada = 1 and u.UsuUsuario is not null
    and S.TarEstagioID IN (235,276,278,294) AND S.TarStatus IN (0,1,5)-- AND S.UsuIDCliente not in (select Y.UsuIDCliente from Solicitacao Y where Y.SolTipID in (710) and Y.SolStatus in (0,1,5))
    GROUP BY U.UsuID, U.UsuNome
)saida
GROUP BY saida.UsuID, saida.UsuNome
```